# Change hard coded url constants for different environments via webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a `ApiCaller.js` module which generate calls to our api server to get data. It has const field **API_URL** which points to server url.
This **API_URL** const changes for **dev** and **prod** environments.

So when I need to deploy to **dev** environment I need to change that url (**API_URL**) manually to point to **dev-api-server** and vice-versa.

I want these configuration parameters outside the code and during build process I want to change them dynamically so that I can build with different settings.

I am using **webpack** to bundle my javascript, html, css files.

Comment: Do you want to expose `API_URL` in `ApiCaller` (you can edit `ApiCaller`) or you want to change hardcoded `API_URL` in `ApiCaller` (you can not edit `ApiCaller`)?

Comment: You have got it in edited answer. Nothing special - just plain old JS.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can store your `API_URL` in webpack config:

```
// this config can be in webpack.config.js or other file with constants
var API_URL = {
    production: JSON.stringify('prod-url'),
    development: JSON.stringify('dev-url')
}

// check environment mode
var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';

// webpack config
module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'API_URL': API_URL[environment]
        })
    ],
    // ...
}
```

Now in your `ApiCaller` you can use `API_URL` as defined variable, which it will be different depend on `process.env.NODE_ENV`:

```
ajax(API_URL).then(/*...*/);
```

---

### (edit) If I have more than production/development config for different environment constants?

Imagine that you have `API_URL` like in above answer, `API_URL_2` and `API_URL_3` which should support different environment settings `production/development/test`

```
var API_URL = {
    production: JSON.stringify('prod-url'),
    development: JSON.stringify('dev-url')
};

var API_URL_2 = {
    production: JSON.stringify('prod-url-2'),
    development: JSON.stringify('dev-url-2'),
    test: JSON.stringify('test-url-2')
};

var API_URL_3 = {
    production: JSON.stringify('prod-url-3'),
    development: JSON.stringify('dev-url-3'),
    test: JSON.stringify('test-url-3')
};

// get available environment setting
var environment = function () {
     switch(process.env.NODE_ENV) {
         case 'production':
             return 'production';
         case 'development':
             return 'development';
         case 'test':
             return 'test';
         default:                // in case ...
             return 'production';
     };
};

// default map for supported all production/development/test settings
var mapEnvToSettings = function (settingsConsts) {
     return settingsConsts[environment()];
};

// special map for not supported all production/development/test settings
var mapAPI_URLtoSettings = function () {
     switch(environment()) {
         case 'production':
             return API_URL.production;
         case 'development':
             return API_URL.development;
         case 'test':                    // don't have special test case
             return API_URL.development;
     };
};

// webpack config
module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'API_URL': mapAPI_URLtoSettings(),
            'API_URL_2': mapEnvToSettings(API_URL_2),
            'API_URL_3': mapEnvToSettings(API_URL_3)
        })
    ],
    // ...
}
```

---

### (edit 2)

1. If you pass string as a environment constant you should use `JSON.stringify`.
2. You don't need to define `new webpack.DefinePlugin` multiple times. You can do it in one object passed to `new webpack.DefinePlugin` - it looks cleaner.

Comment: The problem with this is if you're storing these URL values in a file (other than webpack.config), then they get bundled into your app and support people or whomever has access to production, will not be able to modify these values without requiring a code change, which is the whole point of separating config files from app code in the first place. If you put them in webpack.config, then you run into the issue of overwriting whatever support had updated on the prod server whenever you do a new deployment.

Comment: @muzurBurcu Discussion about capabilities of maintaining dist version of app is different topic than this question. But you are right: you should always create easy to accomplish end documented way of making build of app. These days `npm run:build ... or similar` is necessary step of developing app, doesn't matter if it is developing stage or support stage.

Comment: how can i inject process.env.NODE_ENV to some value such as dev and products? it always is undefined.

Comment: When I went to use this implementation, I could not use the variable `API_URL `. ES-lint was stopping the webpack build from completing so I had to include the line `// eslint-disable-next-line`. Now it works like any variable underneath that comment.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the [define plugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin) to define a `PRODUCTION` variable as follows (or alternatively to `true` if you use different configuration files for the builds):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
})
```

Then in your code you will write something like:

```
var API_URL = PRODUCTION ? 'my-production-url' : 'my-development-url';
```

During compilation webpack will replace `PRODUCTION` with its value (so either `true` or `false`), and this should allow UglifyJS to minify our expression:

```
var API_URL = <true/false> ? 'my-production-url' : 'my-development-url';
```

The worst case scenario is uglify not being able to minify the conditional expression leaving it as is.

Comment: Seems like a minimalistic and feasible solution, any updates on this if the configuration grows ?