# Vue.js img src using absolute path (django+webpack)

Tags: javascript, html, django, vue.js, webpack

I am using django + Vue.js & webpack for development. In my *App.vue* file i try to load img:
`<img src="/static/webapp/img/logo.png" alt="logo">`
In production I use nginx which is directing `/static` path into `static` folder that I share and it's working.
But in the development when i run my django on `localhost:8000` and load this js from my *App.vue* it's trying to get the image from `localhost:8000/static/webapp/img/logo.png`.
I would like it to take from `localhost:8082/static/webapp/img/logo.png` (`localhost:8082` is where webpack is running) where it can be found.
I tryied to change `publicPath` in my *webpack.config.js*:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {  
  module.exports.output.publicPath = 'http://localhost:8082/'
}
```

but it does not change default behaviour and the img asset src is still `localhost:8000/static/webapp/img/logo.png`.
How can I change img assets default base path to another url to make it work?
Cheers.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164102/change-hard-coded-url-constants-for-different-environments-via-webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work it out:

1. When I run webpack node server I add mode environment variable:
   `NODE_ENV=development node server.js`
2. I changed img src to:
   `` <img :src="`${STATIC_URL}/webapp/img/logo.png`" alt="logo"> ``
3. Setup `STATIC_URL` based on `NODE_ENV`:

```
export default {
  ...,
  data () {
    return {
      ...,
      STATIC_URL: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "http://localhost:8082/static" : "/static"
    }
  }
}
```

And it works how it's supposed to. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use window.location.origin to get the current base url. In this way you can avoid any manual mapping based on the NODE_ENV

```
<img :src="`${publicPath}/static/example.jpg`" />

  data() {
    return {
      publicPath: window.location.origin
     }
   },
```